# How to add corresponding strings to a file from another file that it shares a field with?

Tags: bash, shell-script, function

I have two files that both have the field "tumor id". Both are comma delimited. I need to add a field that is uniquely in file 2 to file 1, and I want to add the lines of the field according to their corresponding strings in "tumor id". An example format is:

File 1

```
Tumor_ID, Chromosome, start, end,
xxxxx,       2,        12,    13,
xxxxx,       3,        45,    46,
xxxxx,       3,        48,    49
xxxxx,       3,        51,    52,
nnnnn,       5,       55,    59,
nnnnn,       5,       57,    58,
lllll,      11,       13,    14,
lllll,      12,        16,    17,
eeeee,       2,        51,    52,
zzzzz,       9,      1000,   101,
```

File 2

```
Patient_No., Tumor_ID,  Normal_ID, 
4,            xxxxx,     hhhhh,            
5,            nnnnn,     aaaaa,          
8,            lllll,     ddddd,     
7,            eeeee,     ggggg,     
3,            zzzzz,     nnnnn,
```

How would I create a new field in File 1 (say, -f15) and assign the Normal_ID values from File 2 to their corresponding Tumor_ID values in the newly created file 1 field? Does my question make sense?

Comment: if your records in both files are unique and you can manipulate the order of the records in the files prior to joining them, then you can have a look and the "join" command https://www.baeldung.com/linux/join-command . If not, then you have to choose a scripting lanuage to do so.

Comment: Can you provide sample file1/file2 with at least 10 lines each

Comment: The records in file 2 are unique but the records in file 1 are not. I can't provide an 100% accurate sample file 2 because the actual file has 20 fields, but I can make the above sample files 10 lines.

Comment: I added the commas.

Comment: Is the extra whitespace part of the data in the file, or did you add it to align the data in the question? Do both files have an un-named empty field at the end of each record? (there or trailing commas at the end of each line)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution that works but may need further refinement.

I have removed all spaces and tabs in file2 to make the data comma separated. This can easily be done with

```
tr -d " " <file2 > file-b
```

I have also added a new placeholder field number 5 in file1 (now called file-a) with the initial values of N.A.

This can be done by

```
sed  's/$/\tN.A./' file1 > file-a
```

So our new input files are:

```
$ cat file-a
Tumor_ID, Chromosome, start, end,       N.A.
xxxxx,       2,        12,    13,       N.A.
xxxxx,       3,        45,    46,       N.A.
xxxxx,       3,        48,    49        N.A.
xxxxx,       3,        51,    52,       N.A.
nnnnn,       5,       55,    59,        N.A.
nnnnn,       5,       57,    58,        N.A.
lllll,      11,       13,    14,        N.A.
lllll,      12,        16,    17,       N.A.
eeeee,       2,        51,    52,       N.A.
zzzzz,       9,      1000,   101,       N.A.

$ cat file-b
Patient_No.,Tumor_ID,Normal_ID,
4,xxxxx,hhhhh,
5,nnnnn,aaaaa,
8,lllll,ddddd,
7,eeeee,ggggg,
3,zzzzz,nnnnn,
```

The command to achieve your goal is:

```
$ while IFS="," read a b c;do sed -i "/${b}/{s/N.A./${c}/}" file-a;done <file-b

$ cat file-a
Tumor_ID, Chromosome, start, end,       Normal_ID
xxxxx,       2,        12,    13,       hhhhh
xxxxx,       3,        45,    46,       hhhhh
xxxxx,       3,        48,    49        hhhhh
xxxxx,       3,        51,    52,       hhhhh
nnnnn,       5,       55,    59,        aaaaa
nnnnn,       5,       57,    58,        aaaaa
lllll,      11,       13,    14,        ddddd
lllll,      12,        16,    17,       ddddd
eeeee,       2,        51,    52,       ggggg
zzzzz,       9,      1000,   101,       nnnnn
```

You can prettify the output with your own suitable formatting.

Comment: This reads and writes `file-a` as many times as there are lines in `file-b` which may become very slow for large files. It also uses the tumor ID as a regular expression, which means that an ID that is `100` will match the IDs `1000` and `1100` and others (and may also match other data on each line).

Comment: Also note that if you're using GNU `sed` (which you might be doing as you are using the non-standard `-i` option), you have a code injection vulnerability in your `sed` expression.  Try, for example, `c='uname -a/e;:'; echo 'N.A.' | sed "s/N.A./${c}/"`.  In addition to this, you do not mention the other restrictions you place on the input due to the data being used as regular expressions and as replacement patterns. Basic tools are good, excellent actually, but they often require you to handle every single edge case explicitly, or know the consequences of not doing so.

Comment: I thought we were here to offer each other pointers and guidance -- not provide comprehensive answers or write operating systems. Attacking another member for helping someone else is beneath contempt. No wonder people are leaving forums like this in droves and use chatgpt instead.

Comment: I'm not attacking, I'm pointing out the flaws you need to fix in your answer. Fortunately, these are quite _easy_ to fix: 1) Add the assumptions you make about the contents of the variables `b` and `c`. 2) Ensure that the regular expression in your `sed` expression matches a complete word (using zero-width word boundary matching and anchoring, `^$b\>`, or with `^$b,` if you want to stay with a POSIX expression). 3) Let your loop create a `sed` script that does all the substitutions in one go, _then_ invoke `sed` with that script.

Comment: However, the more natural fit for this problem is probably to use the standard `join` command, assuming it's ok to sort the files on the join field (we don't know that this is the case). `join -t, -1 1 -2 2 -o1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.3 <( tr -d ' ' <file1 | sed 's/,$//' | sort ) <( tr -d ' ' <file2 | sed 's/,$//' | sort -t, -k2,2 )`

Comment: Here's a pipeline that takes care of the last two points that I mentioned: `tr -d ' ' <file2 | while IFS=, read a b c; do printf '/^%s,/s/,*$/,%s/\n' "$b" "$c"; done | sed -f /dev/stdin file1` (note that this also takes care of adding that missing comma at the end of one of the lines in the first file).

Comment: ```tr -d "," <43018_2022_404_MOESM2_ESM.csv >file-a
sed "s/$/\tN.A./" file-a >file-c
 while read $tumor_wgs_aliquot_id $normal_wgs_aliquot_id ;do 
 sed -i '/$tumor_wgs_aliquot_id/{s/N.A./$normal_wgs_aliquot_id/}' file-c;done <pcawg_summary.tsv >43018_2022_404_MOESM2_ESM.norm.csv ``` So this is my updated code, but it doesn't return anything in the output file 43018_2022_404_MOESM2_ESM.norm.csv. Could I have gotten the field names wrong? Also turns out my second file was already a tsv so I skipped the csv to tsv conversion for file 2.

Answer (score -1):

I will assume that the whitespace in the fields and the trailing commas are typos in the question. If they are *actually* part of the data, then clean these up with e.g.

```bash
mlr -I --csv -N clean-whitespace then remove-empty-columns file1.csv file2.csv
```

The command above uses [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to remove the leading and trailing whitespace from each field's value, compress multiple spaces into single spaces, and then remove the columns that end up empty. Note that this is done "in place", overwriting the original files. Remove the `-I` option and redirect to a new filename if you instead want to retain your original files.

This ought to result in two files, `file1.csv`,

```
Tumor_ID,Chromosome,start,end
xxxxx,2,12,13
xxxxx,3,45,46
xxxxx,3,48,49
xxxxx,3,51,52
nnnnn,5,55,59
nnnnn,5,57,58
lllll,11,13,14
lllll,12,16,17
eeeee,2,51,52
zzzzz,9,1000,101
```

... and `file2.csv`,

```
Patient_No.,Tumor_ID,Normal_ID
4,xxxxx,hhhhh
5,nnnnn,aaaaa
8,lllll,ddddd
7,eeeee,ggggg
3,zzzzz,nnnnn
```

You may then perform a relational JOIN operation between these using the `Tumor_ID` field as the join key:

```bash
$ mlr --csv join -f file1.csv -j Tumor_ID file2.csv
Tumor_ID,Chromosome,start,end,Patient_No.,Normal_ID
xxxxx,2,12,13,4,hhhhh
xxxxx,3,45,46,4,hhhhh
xxxxx,3,48,49,4,hhhhh
xxxxx,3,51,52,4,hhhhh
nnnnn,5,55,59,5,aaaaa
nnnnn,5,57,58,5,aaaaa
lllll,11,13,14,8,ddddd
lllll,12,16,17,8,ddddd
eeeee,2,51,52,7,ggggg
zzzzz,9,1000,101,3,nnnnn
```

Removing the unwanted `Patient_No.` field is done with an extra `cut` operation (the `-x` option to the `cut` sub-command says "remove the fields named with `-f`"):

```bash
$ mlr --csv join -f file1.csv -j Tumor_ID then cut -x -f Patient_No. file2.csv
Tumor_ID,Chromosome,start,end,Normal_ID
xxxxx,3,45,46,hhhhh
xxxxx,3,48,49,hhhhh
xxxxx,3,51,52,hhhhh
nnnnn,5,55,59,aaaaa
nnnnn,5,57,58,aaaaa
lllll,11,13,14,ddddd
lllll,12,16,17,ddddd
eeeee,2,51,52,ggggg
zzzzz,9,1000,101,nnnnn
```

Instead of removing the unwanted field(s), we may want to say precisely what fields we want to keep and in what order. This is particularly handy if the second file has many other fields and you want the `Normal_ID` field from there. The `-o` option to the `cut` sub-command below indicates that the fields mentioned with `-f` should not just be extracted but also ordered in the order mentioned.

```bash
mlr --csv join -f file1.csv -j Tumor_ID then cut -o -f Tumor_ID,Chromosome,start,end,Normal_ID file2.csv
```

Comment: mlr not a standard command. and has to be installed. It is best to stick to basic tools.

Comment: @dhm If you tried to do anything by that rule, you'd have difficulty doing anything on a modern Unix system :-)  The package system on every Unix you might consider using will allow you to install Miller with one easy command.  Unless you consider the package manager non-standard too (because it is).  Unfortunately, even the Linux kernel has to be kept up to date with the package manager, so you'd find it difficult to not use it.